# Разделение определения класса на несколько разных заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++, header

Я бы хотел знать, насколько это правомерно и эффективно (вообще, это реализуется и вроде бы работает). Язык C++, да.

К примеру, есть большой класс, который можно условно поделить на модули. Эти модули, однако, достаточно сильно связаны друг с другом, постоянно вызывают методы друг друга, и так далее. Скажем, один исполняет, другой контролирует, третий обслуживает. По большей части, это для удобства, чтобы не прокручивать тонны кода и не искать какой-то там функционал.

То есть, разделение на несколько классов довольно затруднительно, и при этом придётся бороться с экземплярами этих классов для достижения единства данных в уже условном большом классе (`static` совсем не подходит: вдруг придётся запускать этот большой класс параллельно, и тут данные не должны пересекаться, т.е. должны быть разные экземпляры?). К тому же, я не хочу, чтобы кто-либо видел тот или иной функционал этих возможных классов, кроме того, кому их возможности действительно нужно использовать, а это максимум - не дальше границ этого большого класса, а на деле - не дальше границ областей видимости тех или иных его модулей, которые стали бы классами (чуть позже об этом). Думаю, сделать можно, но муторно.

Но в разных модулях (скажем, мы уже их разбили на разные .cpp-файлы) будут необходимы разные поля данных, разные описания методов. И чтобы не вываливать на них целый стоп всего подряд из одного заголовочного файла, можно было бы разделить на разные заголовочные, подключая каждый к своему модулю. Некоторые поля и некоторые прототипы функций будут встречаться в нескольких заголовочных файлах, но сами функции будут реализованы только где-то в одном месте.

Примерно это имею в виду:

```
// A.h
#pragma once

class MyClass 
{
MyClass();
void func1();
void func2();
}

* * *

// A.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{ /* какой-то код */ }

MyClass::func1()
{ func2(); }   // func1 прекрасно видит func2

* * *

// B.h
#pragma once

class MyClass 
{
void func2();
void func3();
}

* * *

// B.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "B.h"

MyClass::func2()
{ /* какой-то код */ }

MyClass::func3()
{ func1(); }   // нет, он не будет компилироваться, func1 ему не известна
```

Comment: Если у вас так много методов в классе, что _даже декларацию класса_ хочется разбить на куски, может быть, вам таки нужно потрудиться и разрефакторить его на 10 мелких классов? То, что разные куски сильно переплетены — это какая-то спагетти-логика. Попробуйте упростить структуру вашего кода.

Comment: Если постараться, разбить можно, но я уже говорил про возникающие проблемы: единство данных и доступность функционала. Данные должны быть едиными для какой-то одной линейки событий так, чтобы этих линеек можно было бы сделать несколько, а данные между ними не пересекались (никакой статики, то есть). Придётся создавать какой-то ещё мини-класс, который будет всё это контролировать и в котором вся работа и будет происходить (он вызывает всё остальное). Во-вторых, доступность к этим мелким классам должна быть серьёзно ограничена, их интерфейсы должны быть доступны не всем.

Comment: да, это логично, что нужно делать мелкие-helper-классы. Совет все-таки разрисовать что есть сейчас и к чему стремитесь в наглядном виде. Почти наверняка придет понимание как лучше сделать.

> их интерфейсы должны быть доступны не всем
ну, в С++ есть такие механизмы. Начать от того, что можно использовать namespaces и вложенные классы, кончая тем, что можно ограничить доступность членов класса и использовать дружбу (friendship is magic (r)!)

Comment: Все эти проблемы — мелочь по сравнению с другой проблемой: _у вас есть класс с миллионом обязанностей_.

Comment: А разве прямым ответом на поставленный вопрос не будет просто "нет, так сделать нельзя"? Т.е. разбить декларацию класса на разные заголовки невозможно?

Comment: @andy, я уже писал, что разбить можно, и это вполне работает. Из плюсов - отсутствие тех двух проблем, о которых писал, из минусов - можно в заголовочных файлах запутаться. Ну и, мол, перегруженность класса, хотя без этого придётся бороться с абстрактными, вложенными классами и тому подобное (не знаю точно), и никакая дружба сама по себе тут не поможет, так как она предоставляет доступ ко всем закрытым полям и методам, пусть и для конкретной функции.

Comment: А как Вы это собирать будете? Включить куда либо и A.h и B.h одновременно не получится - ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что у Вас получится 2 разных класса с одним именем, и как только Вы попытаетесь где-либо использовать функционал, описанный в разных заголовках - вылетит ошибка компиляции.

Comment: @andy, нет, никаких ошибок компиляции не было, по крайней мере, я использовал MSVC известно на чём, и из любого заголовочного файла можно было перейти к любому .cpp-файлу, где это было реализовано, а из каждого .cpp-файла можно было перейти к любому заголовочному файлу, где эта функция была описана. Естественно, описания должны быть одинаковыми. И функция, реализованная в модуле А, но описанная в заголовке и модуля B, из модуля B прекрасно вызывалась и исполнялась. Два разных класса у меня было бы при разных пространствах имён.

Comment: Если описания одинаковы - зачем 2 заголовка с одинаковым описанием? Я запутался...

Comment: @andy, 2 заголовка потому, что у них разный набор описаний. Те описания, которые должны быть в разных заголовках, являются идентичными по написанию. То есть, я выше приводил абстрактный пример этого в коде. Несколько заголовков дают в итоге единый класс, но в файлах реализации видно только у каждого своя часть этого класса, и эти части могут пересекаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закрываю вопрос, так как никто не станет отвечать. Есть обсуждение выше, из которого следует, что:

- Это работает;
- Но это может привести к путанице с header'ами;
- Это значит, что существует класс с большим количеством обязанностей, который многим кажется излишним, и в команде разработчиков такой код бы вызвал соответствующее непонимание.

Рефакторинг порождает две проблемы:

- Работа с экземплярами: алгоритм должен поддерживать единство данных, но только в рамках одной линейки общих событий, причём этих "линеек" может быть несколько параллельных;
- Доступность: интерфейсы классов должны быть невидимы извне, но доступны там, где это действительно нужно.

Эти проблемы я решил (надеюсь) таким образом:

- Один класс как был, так и остался, но теперь выделены подклассы, отвечающие за модульность и которые вложены друг в друга;
- Работа с ними происходит через указатели, кроме случаев обращения к статическим методам;
- Каждый вложенный модуль объявляется в приватной зоне класса, и в этот модуль тоже может быть ещё что-либо вложено;
- Из-за этого возникают проблемы, связанные с накладными расходами на вложенность и необходимость расписания кода в стиле `А::B::C::func() {...}`;
- Однако это решает проблему доступности извне;
- Но при этом остаётся проблема нежелательной доступности изнутри, так как вложенные классы по всей видимости могут обращаться к `private` окаймляющего класса, что не указано в стандарте и не рекомендуется;
- Все данные хранятся в некотором хранилище с `get/set`-методами, являющимся закрытым для доступа снаружи вложенным классом;
- Экземпляры этого хранилища поочередно передаются от класса к классу: каждый раз в конструкторе окаймляющего класса вызывается параметризованный конструктор вложенного класса, в который скидывается экземпляр хранилища через указатель;
- В деструкторе всё соответственным образом уничтожается.

В итоге код изменился в объёмах:

- Уменьшились заголовочные файлы ввиду отсутствия необходимости прописывать совпадающие поля и методы;
- Появился отдельный модуль с данными;
- Заметно увеличились файлы реализации, так как теперь работа происходит через указатели либо через их совокупность, а передача универсального указателя `void*` на некоторые данные в `get`-методе хранилища требует последующего `static_cast<type*>(void* ptr)`.

---

Если честно, я ожидал ответ, как мой изначальный вариант обработается среднестатистическим msvc (и другими компиляторами) и компоновщиком, будет всё выглядеть действительно ли как я задумал или нет с точки зрения сборки и прочего, но увы. И указания на "спагетти" относительно действительно тесно связанных друг с другом контроллера, обработчика и "обслуживателя в процессе работы", представляющих те или иные аспекты единого целого - не думаю, что они были достаточно уместны и относились к теме заданного вопроса.

Comment: Если честно, мне безразличны отрицательные оценки, так что можете хоть тревогу ставить.